# Trigger polymer component re-rendering

Tags: javascript, html, polymer

I started exploring polymer, tried few things to understand the concept, but cannot get it working properly.
I'm using sampler-scaffold element from sources of this tutorial http://www.polymer-project.org/components/paper-elements/demo.html
It creates iframe with min-height: 500px and loads my page inside.

on my page I have my custom element:

```
<polymer-element name="test-element" extends="core-selector">
  <template>
    <core-menu>
    <template repeat="{{line in lines}}">
      <core-item label="{{line.name}}" src="{{line.icon}}"></core-item>
    </template>
    </core-menu>
  </template>
  <script>
    Polymer('test-element', {
      ready: function() {
        this.lines = []
      }
    });
  </script>
</polymer-element>
```

and load some data for my element using angular js:

```
$http.get(BASE_URL+'/getItems').success(function(data) {
  document.querySelector("test-element").lines = data;
})
```

It works, and sometimes iframe being resized to fit the content, but most of the time it stays 500px in height and not all items shown.
If I then resize window, it gets re-rendered properly and fits the content.

I cannot figure out what's exactly the problem, is it data received with delay (which should not cause the issue), is it animation of root element - sampler-scaffold, which prevents iframe to be rendered in time or something else. Is there a way to trigger re-rendering manually? Or do I need to monitor data change on my element and then do something with it?

**UPDATE**

Created repo with minimal code to reproduce
`https://github.com/s-a-y/test`
Clone it, run npm install and npm start

While doing that I learned, that the issue comes from http request. In my real code I do request to remote server and it takes some time, that's why sometimes response comes in time to be rendered properly, sometimes it doesn't.
In test project I request local file, so initially was no problem, I had to add timeout to reproduce the issue. If you set timeout to 0, it's rendered properly.

Comment: could you set up Jsbin or codepen for your code.

Comment: There isn't enough information here for us to help. Could you post a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve), ideally using an online editor as @AjayBeniwal suggested? In short, the code as you've given it here should work without further changes, setting `lines` on your `test-element` should cause it to rerender, no other steps necessary. It's likely that there's a subtle bug or just a typo going on, but it's impossible to tell without more info.

Comment: For jsbin too many dependencies, but I've created small github repo and updating my question

Comment: Perhaps a repeat of the following question.


  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24811051/polymer-repeat-template-refresh