# Force Polymer repeat to be re-evaluated

Tags: javascript, polymer

Is there a way to force the re-evaluation of an array that is bound via repeat?

I have code similar to the following:

```
<template repeat="{{ item in items | filter(search) | sort }}">
<div class="item">
    <p>{{ item.title }}</p>
    <p>Favorite: {{ item.favorited }}</p>
</div>
</template>
```

In the `filter` function i specify that only items should be shown that have the property `favorited` set to true (among other things). When I programmatically change that property the repeat isn't re-evaluated and thus not up to date.

Currently I'm using the approach as shown in the polymer tutorial:

```
<template repeat="{{ item in items | filter(search) | sort }}">
<div class="item" hidden?="{{!item.favorited}}">
    <p>{{ item.title }}</p>
    <p>Favorite: {{ item.favorited }}</p>
</div>
</template>
```

This works, but I'd really like the function `filter` to take care of the filtering. Telling Polymer when to re-evaluate the repeat is to specify a parameter to the function, as I did with `filter(search)`. However I can not specify `favorited` as a parameter, since that is a property of a single item of the array.

Long story short: Is there a possibility to manually decide when the repeat function should be re-run?

Thank you very much!

Comment: can you link to documentation for the use of filters with Polymer, also you can customize this [jsbin](http://jsbin.com/foyile/3/edit) to explain your problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could try the answer suggested here and see what happens. The question might not be the same but it apparently it 'forces a refresh' so it'll be worth a shot.
[polymer repeat template "refresh"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24811051/polymer-repeat-template-refresh/24814343#24814343)

And I feel the answer here might also be related. Read the answer to the end.
https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/polymer-dev/CMQRzKPV5Ww